# Using Python applications

Tags: python

I downloaded and installed a Python-based application according to [this page](http://comix.sourceforge.net/download.html). How do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily install comix via software center (or by [clicking here](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/comix)) that way it is automatically added to your gnome menus and updated via the update manager.

Comment: I see, I did not find the application in .deb form - thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to install from software center or apt-get as mentioned above, but since you have already installed it. typing `comix` on the terminal is your best bet as comix creates a symlink in your executable path. you can also copy comix.desktop file from the source in that link to your /usr/share/applications/ to create a menu.